# Dependency Injection In Blazor Component file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a blazor component in my application:

```
public class IndexComponent : ComponentBase
{
    public string ContentRoot { get; set; }
    public string WebRoot { get; set; }
    private IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment;

    public IndexComponent(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        HostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        //Some Code Here
    }
}
```

I am trying to use DI in my app , for example IHostingEnvironment.

Code give no compile time error here but when i run it than in code behind file of this razor (Index.razor.g.cs file):

```
public class Index : IndexComponent
```

at this line it says:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter hostingEnvironment of IndexComponent.IndexComponent

This can be solved by using @inject IHostingEnvironment in Razor file but I am moving my function block from Razor to IndexComponent.cs file so need it there.

Neither of it works in below way:

```
[Inject]
IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment
```

What will work here?

Note: No use of ViewModel

**Update 1**

In StartUp.cs by adding namespace

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal;
```

And than

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(new HostingEnvironment());
```

It is now able to register IHostingEnvironment on client side project but it does not have values for its properties (contentrootpath and webrootpath).

Only one thing is available here which is EnvironmentName and its value is always Production ,

Comment: They are nothing wrong in your code. It looks like you are creating some new index or index component by hand somewhere.

Comment: @daniherrera yes , this is the standrad way to seprate your code from html markup in another file and inherit ComponentBase in that class file , Everything is fule untill we use Dependency Injection in ASP.Net Blazor. It is giving error

Comment: I use DI on code components extensively without problems. Are you trying to create a new instance of component by hand in someplace? This kind of errors ( missing DI element) are usually raised on run time not in compiling time.

Comment: No , there is no use of new keyword to create instance of component

Comment: @daniherrera Please see Update 1

Comment: ok, `client-side`tag added, `IHostingEnvironment` has no sense on client side.

Comment: @daniherrera ok , what about Iconfiguration  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this comment:

> WASM: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'HostingEnvironment' on type 'JewelShut.Client.Pages.Index'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'

I'm guessing this is a **client side** Blazor application. (My apologies if I'm wrong with my guess.). On client side Blazor the `IHostingEnvironment` is not registered by default in DI container. Still the error says that the service you are trying to inject is not registered. To register a service:

In the Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //few sample for you
    services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
    services.AddAuthorizationCore();

    //register the required services
    //services.Add...
}
```

If the injected service is registered the way @Henk Holterman has suggested is the right answer.

[Di in blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: is not default services work without registering them  ? The template i am using is server sider asp.net core hosted which have three projects - client , server , shared . I have issue in client project

Comment: the hosted version is not sever side Blazor! The hosted version uses a asp.net core as a server. Sever side Blazor does not create separated project for sever, client and shared. The hosted template still uses WebAssembly for client side. DI is not shared.

Comment: Do wee need to register default services on client side project ??

Comment: Please See Update 1

Comment: Here is the doc of [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-2.2). It states that it will read out some properties from environment variables and some properties require file access. A browser does not allow any file access for security reasons. That is why using this interface in the browser does not make much sense.
If you really need some context from the browser I would look into it if you could get the info from javascript side and use the jsinterop to parse the data. That is your best shot

Answer (score 12):

Update:

The error is from WebAssembly, so it is a client-side app. There is no HostingEnvironment on the client and therefore the service is not registered. It would be useless if it was.

So, step back: Why do (you think) you need it?

---

You should make it a protected or public  read/write property:

```
// in IndexComponent
[Inject]
protected IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; set; }
```

and remove the constructor parameters.

Side note: `IHostingEnvironment` is marked as obsolete.

Comment: WASM: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'HostingEnvironment' on type 'JewelShut.Client.Pages.Index'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'.

Comment: By this way this message pop up in console

Comment: It works for me on RC1, server-side. Ahh, it is client-side. I will update.

Comment: Yes issue is in client side project part , works fine in server project

Comment: So what do you need a HostingEnvironment  for on the client?

Comment: Need to access webrootpath and contentrootpath on client

Comment: Please see Update 1

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that for Blazor you need a slightly different interface, namely `IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment`.

From this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0), what you should inject is:

```
@inject IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment HostEnvironment
```